# Updating multiple Labels with kivy

Tags: python, label, kivy, clock, displayobject

Hello i'm relatively new to python and kivy and I've been looking around but i cant quite find the answer, i'm trying to make a hub where I can display live data from my rasberry-pi. I made a clock widget using a Label, and it updates time, but when i try to add my CPU usage only one label shows up. I thought the widgets might be covering each other but I used *size_hint* and it wont help. When i run the code below, only the ***timex*** will show up and only if i delete the **Clock.schedule_interval(display32.timex, (1))** will the ***updatex *** display.

Thanks alot for the help

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.label import Label

from kivy.clock import Clock

from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

import psutil

from kivy.lang import Builder

import time

class Display(Label, FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Display, self).__init__()



    def updatex(self, *args):

        self.cpu2 = psutil.cpu_percent()
        self.text=str(self.cpu2)
        self.size_hint=(.5, .25)
        self.pos=(500, 500)
        self.texture_size=(0.1,0.1)

    def timex(self, *args):
        self.time2 = time.asctime()
        self.text = str(self.time2)
        self.size_hint = (.5, .25)
        self.pos = (30, 500)
        self.size_hint=(0.1,0.1)


class TimeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        display32 = Display()

        Clock.schedule_interval(display32.updatex, (1))
        Clock.schedule_interval(display32.timex, (1))
        return display32

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TimeApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing both labels to the clock, you can define a widget, add both labels and start the clock on the widget.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock
import psutil
import time

class Display(Widget):
    def draw(self, *args):
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.add_widget(Label(text=str(psutil.cpu_percent()), pos=(500, 500)))
        self.add_widget(Label(text=str(time.asctime()), pos=(30, 500)))

class TimeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        display32 = Display()
        Clock.schedule_interval(display32.draw, 1)       
        return display32

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TimeApp().run()
```